# How do you display Dataframe column names sorted?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe that has over 250 columns.  I can display the columns using `df.printSchema` or I can get it using `df.columns`, is there a way to get column names (just the column names - not the content of columns)in sorted order asc/desc ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

PySpark:

```
sorted(df.columns)
```

Scala:

```
df.columns.sorted
```

Comment: How to get this list of columns in the original sequence instead?

Answer (score 1):

If we also need to view the data type along with sorted by column name :

```
sorted(df.dtypes)
```

`df.dtypes` - returns an array of tuples `[(column_name, type), (column_name, type)...]`

`sorted` - by default will sort by the first value in each tuple. So we will get the desired result of sorting by column names and get type of each column as well.

Comment: This was helpful - thank you. Is it possible to get the output in a list format, just as  `sorted(df.columns)` provides?